# How works sendCommand?

Tags: java, javascript, apache, command, send

I don't understand sendCommand I have to convert a string to byte to execute in this code

```
public void sendCommand(byte command) 
   throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException
```

Sends a command byte to the remote peer, adding the IAC prefix.
This method does not wait for any response. Messages sent by the remote end can be handled by registering an appropriate TelnetOptionHandler.

Parameters:
command - the code for the command

Comment: what is it exactly you don't understand? As it appears this method sends some command (in which the byte is the command that will be sent) somewhere. it is possible to send 256 different commands, since the command is a bytecode.

Comment: actually;i want to send show ip ospf inter brief while apache.common telnet is working i'm in right way?Do you have any advice?

Comment: There is too little information for us to say anything about this method. What is the library of this method? class?

Comment: this in apache.common telnetclient i tried to do this like that  String example = "show ip ospf inter brief";
     byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();            System.out.println( tc.sendCommand(bytes)); but it isnot working

Comment: I am sorry, but it is still not clear what is not working. Could you please show more of your code?

Comment: OutputStream outstr = tc.getOutputStream();

                byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                int ret_read = 0;

                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ret_read = System.in.read(buff);
                        if(ret_read > 0)                System.out.println( tc.sendcommand(500));
         System.out.println("AYT response:" + tc.sendAYT(500)); i tried to sen show ip ospf inter brief in command but it isnot wroking

Comment: you're using the wrong method to send commands.  see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18562607/262852  The API documentation is poorly written.