# sending byte commands to Apache TelnetClient

Tags: java, api, telnet, apache-commons

Looking at:

http://www.asciitable.com/

I want to send a CHAR LF, decimal value 10, and also a Chr 1, decimal byte value 49.  Followed, again, by a LF.  (I **think** that is the sequence which the telnet server at rainmaker.wunderground.com 3000 expects.)  This is keyboard entry which is captured from standard input.  I'm explicitly not using the Apache `IOUtil` [example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/trunk/src/main/java/examples/util/IOUtil.java).

It's necessary to thread read/writes to Apache `TelnetClient`, based on [an example WeatherTelnet program](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/net/tags/NET_1_0_0/src/java/examples/weatherTelnet.java).  The `TelnetClient.sendCommand()` [API specifies](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html#sendCommand%28byte%29) that it takes a byte argument, which, I **think** I'm sending.  But is it the correct byte?  And sent correctly?

The first command expected by the telnet weather server (see below) is to press enter, which I take to be a LF, which I take as `Byte by = 10`.

It *seems* like the other commands, like integers, are being sent as commands, at least so far as I can tell.  Any help interpreting this output and debugging it would be greatly appreciated:

Executing the JAR:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -jar NetBeansProjects/SSCCE/dist/SSCCE.jar 
print..
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:

Press Return for menu
or enter 3 letter forecast city code-- 

                 WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU
                ******************************
                 1) U.S. forecasts and climate data
                 2) Canadian forecasts
                 3) Current weather observations
                 4) Ski conditions
                 5) Long-range forecasts
                 6) Latest earthquake reports
                 7) Severe weather
                 8) Hurricane advisories
                 9) Weather summary for the past month
                10) International data
                11) Marine forecasts and observations
                12) Ultraviolet light forecast
                 X) Exit program
                 C) Change scrolling to screen
                 H) Help and information for new users
                 ?) Answers to all your questions
                   Selection:1
sent    49  cmd 1

          Not a valid option. Type a number 1 to 12.

                 WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU
                ******************************
                 1) U.S. forecasts and climate data
                 2) Canadian forecasts
                 3) Current weather observations
                 4) Ski conditions
                 5) Long-range forecasts
                 6) Latest earthquake reports
                 7) Severe weather
                 8) Hurricane advisories
                 9) Weather summary for the past month
                10) International data
                11) Marine forecasts and observations
                12) Ultraviolet light forecast
                 X) Exit program
                 C) Change scrolling to screen
                 H) Help and information for new users
                 ?) Answers to all your questions
                   Selection:1
sent    49  cmd 1

          Not a valid option. Type a number 1 to 12.

                 WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU
                ******************************
                 1) U.S. forecasts and climate data
                 2) Canadian forecasts
                 3) Current weather observations
                 4) Ski conditions
                 5) Long-range forecasts
                 6) Latest earthquake reports
                 7) Severe weather
                 8) Hurricane advisories
                 9) Weather summary for the past month
                10) International data
                11) Marine forecasts and observations
                12) Ultraviolet light forecast
                 X) Exit program
                 C) Change scrolling to screen
                 H) Help and information for new users
                 ?) Answers to all your questions
                   Selection:^Cthufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```

code:

```
package weathertelnet;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

public final class Telnet {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Telnet.class.getName());
    private TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();

    public Telnet() throws SocketException, IOException {
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("rainmaker.wunderground.com");
        int port = 3000;
        telnetClient.connect(host, port);

        final InputStream inputStream = telnetClient.getInputStream();
        final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Character> clq = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Thread print = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                out.println("print..");
                try {
                    char ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                    while (255 > ch && ch >= 0) {
                        clq.add(ch);
                        out.print(ch);
                        ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    out.println("cannot read inputStream:\t" + ex);
                }
            }
        };


        Thread read = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                try {
                    do {
                        String command = in.readLine();
                        byte[] bytes = command.getBytes();
                        byte b = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                            b = bytes[i];
                            String cmd = new String(bytes);
                            telnetClient.sendCommand(b);
                            out.println("sent\t" + b + "\tcmd\t" + cmd);
                        }
                        b=10;
                        telnetClient.sendCommand(b);
                    } while (true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        };
        print.start();
        read.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        new Telnet();
    }
}
```

regular tel

```
net:

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ telnet rainmaker.wunderground.com 3000
Trying 38.102.137.140...
Connected to rainmaker.wunderground.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:

Press Return for menu
or enter 3 letter forecast city code-- 

                 WEATHER UNDERGROUND MAIN MENU
                ******************************
                 1) U.S. forecasts and climate data
                 2) Canadian forecasts
                 3) Current weather observations
                 4) Ski conditions
                 5) Long-range forecasts
                 6) Latest earthquake reports
                 7) Severe weather
                 8) Hurricane advisories
                 9) Weather summary for the past month
                10) International data
                11) Marine forecasts and observations
                12) Ultraviolet light forecast
                 X) Exit program
                 C) Change scrolling to screen
                 H) Help and information for new users
                 ?) Answers to all your questions
                   Selection:1

                         CITY FORECAST MENU
                ---------------------------------------------------
                1) Print forecast for selected city
                2) Print climatic data for selected city
                3) Display 3-letter city codes for a selected state
                4) Display all 2-letter state codes
                M) Return to main menu
                X) Exit program
                ?) Help
                   Selection:x
Connection closed by foreign host.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: should I be using:  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetOptionHandler.html  perhaps?

Comment: duplicate of, or similar to:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/17926779/262852

Comment: see also http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.commons.user/27223

Answer (score 1):

```
package sscce;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

public final class Telnet {

    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Telnet.class.getName());
    private TelnetClient telnetClient = new TelnetClient();

    public Telnet() throws SocketException, IOException {
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("rainmaker.wunderground.com");
        int port = 3000;
        telnetClient.connect(host, port);

        final InputStream inputStream = telnetClient.getInputStream();
        final OutputStream outputStream = telnetClient.getOutputStream();

        Thread print = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                out.println("print..");
                try {
                    char ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                    while (255 > ch && ch >= 0) {
                        out.print(ch);
                        ch = (char) inputStream.read();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    out.println("cannot read inputStream:\t" + ex);
                }
            }
        };


        Thread read = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader bufferedInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                try {
                    do {
                        byte b = 10;
                        outputStream.write(10);
                        outputStream.flush();
                        String command = bufferedInput.readLine();
                        byte[] bytes = command.getBytes();
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                        outputStream.flush();
                    } while (true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        };
        print.start();
        read.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        new Telnet();
    }
}
```